# Why webpack loaders return with "module.exports = ..."?

Tags: webpack

Why loader return with 
return "module.exports = " + JSON.stringify(input); 
instead of return JSON.stringify(input);

What's the point of it?

This is the json-loader.

```
/*
    MIT License http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
    Author Tobias Koppers @sokra
*/
module.exports = function(source) {
    this.cacheable && this.cacheable();
    var value = typeof source === "string" ? JSON.parse(source) : source;
    this.value = [value];
    return "module.exports = " + JSON.stringify(value) + ";";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it is JSON, an image or some other file type, Webpack's loaders will always return a JS module that exports the content, so that it can be imported into other modules generated by Webpack as a dependency, with additional transforms applied after the module is generated if you're using a different module standard (AMD, UMD, etc.).

If you wish to bypass Webpack's module resolution and plugin transforms, then you should use [`copy-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin). This way you would have the raw JSON file, but then you will have to know the public URL and load the file yourself, via XHR or `fetch()`, before you can use it in your sources.